# Элементы не разбегаются flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Я решил попробовать свои навыки в flex-box, но не могу понять, почему свойство не работает, вот `css` и `html`:

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
}

body{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-columns: auto;
   -moz-columns: auto;
   -o-columns: auto;
   columns: auto;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

.header{
   background: #d75fe2;
   padding: 20px;
}

.main{
   background: #bc7ab4;
   padding: 20px;
}

.footer{
   background: #d75fe2;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="header">
      <div class="logo">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
      <div class="link">Lorem ipsum.</div>
      <div class="link">Lorem ipsum.</div>
   </header>

   <main class="main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla aperiam iste sequi illum, sunt recusandae eveniet.</p>
   </main>

   <footer class="footer">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Так вот, элементы должны были разбежаться на равное расстояние, но что-то пошло не так, не поможете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно написано, просто высоту в тело добавьте.

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
}

body{
height: 500px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-columns: auto;
   -moz-columns: auto;
   -o-columns: auto;
   columns: auto;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

.header{
   background: #d75fe2;
   padding: 20px;
}

.main{
   background: #bc7ab4;
   padding: 20px;
}

.footer{
   background: #d75fe2;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="header">
      <div class="logo">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
      <div class="link">Lorem ipsum.</div>
      <div class="link">Lorem ipsum.</div>
   </header>

   <main class="main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla aperiam iste sequi illum, sunt recusandae eveniet.</p>
   </main>

   <footer class="footer">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 100% не работает?

Comment: body{
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}
Идеально работает

Comment: В процентах высоту высоту задавать не всегда получиться. Если хотите относительно окна то используйте vh. https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent